# XCode Label in same view as embedded table view will not display

Tags: iphone, xcode, label

I have a view that contains an embedded table and a label. A web service is called and the label should display the value from the call. The call returns the appropriate string, but the label refuses to set to anything.. not even hard-coded strings work.

Here is what I declare in the header:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
```

Here is my implementation in viewDidLoad...(already synthesized textLabel):

```
textLabel.text = @"For the love of God PLEASE display!!";
//also tried with self.textLabel.text.... but that shouldn't matter... right?
//also tried the following line to no avail:
//[self.textLabel setText:@"This didnt work either"];
```

I have tried putting the label inside the same container as the table, but that did not work either. The only time the label shows something is if I set the value in interface builder.

I feel like this may be due to some UI painting/refreshing issues associated with having an embedded table view in my UIview. Anyone out there have any ideas?

Comment: have you connected your label property in xib as outlet properly?

Comment: I think your IBOutlet has not been set properly. Try to remove your label from xib and add a new label.

Comment: I used interface builder to connect the label to my header file. (click and drag, then set name etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you reload your table after call web services for label change?

Comment: The table loads it's web service values fine. It's the label I can't seem to change. I try to set the text of the label the line after the [super viewDidLoad]. Why would I have to reload the table?

Comment: OK so you received all data in table then Where is your label in table which you want to be change?

Comment: You will try this.....   [  textlabel settext:@"welcome"];             I think this will work for you

Comment: vishiphone - it is a UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

Comment: The label isn't in the table. I tried including it in the table to see if that work but it did not. Currently it is outside the table.

Comment: You should create dynamic label for insert in tableview that is better but first thing you try to change your label string so use above method it will surly work.  There is many way you also create one string object and pass that object to label that will also work

Comment: I tried [ textlabel settext:@"welcome"]; if you look at my commented out code. For whatever reason the text attribute of the label is still nil after this. I will try this solution in the morning when I have access to the server again

Comment: Found my solution at 4am last night! Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this and check

```
 textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yourStringFromWebCall];
```

or

```
 textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:@"%@", yourStringFromWebCall];
```

Also check once whether you have connected the IBOutlet in the nib file to the label... May be that is the issue here

Comment: Interesting idea. I think the string from the web call isn't quite an NSSTring but a similar class of string. The web server is down for maintenance but I will try your approach in the morning. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @SeanGerhardt but u told textLabel.text = @"For the love of God PLEASE display!!"; is not working na..

Comment: Yeah, it's really not related to the web service at all right now. Something to do with the UI

Comment: It didn't have to do with string formatting apparently. Thanks anyways for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

your IBOutlet has not been set properly. Try to remove your label from xib and add a new label.

Connect your IBOutlet again.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
```

Comment: [yourtableview reloaddata]; Have you applied this ?

Comment: Check the control by using breakpoint that the control is reaching on that particular location or not ?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution... 
I knew the table cells were getting filled in with the proper values just fine, so I set the

```
[textLabel setText:webServiceText]
```

just before the return for the following method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
```

And voila! It works now! 
I still find it incredibly strange that it wouldn't work before with all the other places I tried, so if anyone has explanations, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: This sounds like your label was actually inside the cell - your question (and all the answerers) gave the impression it was a separate label that was nothing to do with the table. If it was inside the prototype cell then it would not exist at viewDidLoad.

Comment: Give proper solution don't try to copy paste.